# css, flexbox padding vs gap. Что лучше для отступов?

Tags: html, css

Вижу что некоторые верстают используя padding для элементов flex контейнера, но есть же gap который работает и у flex и у grid. Отступы в виде padding уже полностью устарели или у них есть какие-то преимущества к примеру в виде резиновости по сравнению с gap?

Comment: У всех них разные предназначения: `margin` задаёт отступ **снаружи** элемента, `padding` задаёт отступ **внутри** элемента, `gap` задаёт отступ **между** элементами. Где что лучше подходит - то там и применять, по ситуации

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вы в вопросе имели в виду не внутренний отступ `padding`, а внешний `margin`, так как расстояние между flex-элементами задает именно он?

На мой взгляд, причина использования `margin` вместо `gap`, чаще всего, банальная привычка. Свойство `gap` для модуля `flex` относительно новое и достаточно широкую поддержку браузерами оно обрело лишь сравнительно недавно.

Лично мне не известно о каких-либо преимуществах старого-доброго `margin` перед `gap`, в том числе в плане адаптива. Скорее даже наоборот - свойство `gap` имеет хорошее преимущество в том, чтобы задавать отступытолько внутри между элементами и не затрагивают отступ от крайнего элемента к стенке контейнера, избавляя нас от необходимости использовать в нем отрицательный отступ.

Возможно, для элементов внутри flex-контейнера я бы использовал `margin` в том случае, если по какой-либо причине расстояние между разными элементами будет не одинаковым и одно общее свойство `gap` не поможет. Но надо исходить из конкретной задачи

Comment: Именно padding, не знаю насколько это известная штука: нужен `box-sizing: border-box;` и задать padding элементам flex контейнера и после чего `flex-basis: 33,333%` к примеру для трех элементов. Таким образом эти 3 элемента будут учитывать у себя в своих 33,333% padding тоже. C margin такого не прокатит насколько я знаю. Там будет 33,333% * 3 + margin-ы - т.е. выход за границы контейнера

Comment: @Alegro flex-контейнер в принципе не позволит выйти за его границы (если не баловаться с flex-shrink), значение flex-basis или box-sizing в этом плане почти ни на что не повлияют

Comment: @andreymal Не знаю, я учился так, зачем-то же использовали padding вместо margin. Да и мне он удобнее т.к. flex его учитывает в отличии от margin-а. создал класс row сделал его flex-контейнером, а в него columns в которых уже нужный объект, этим columns и задаешь padding.

Comment: @Alegro вы что-то путаете, внутри flex-контейнеров замечательно работает и margin тоже